# New San Francisco Text Font with systemFontOfSize

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uifont

The new San Francisco Font is divided in 2 categories, Display and Text.
When I call systemFontOfSize I always get fonts in the display category. Is there a way to get fonts from the text category ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call systemFontOfSize and enter a size less than 20.0. For more information about the difference between text and display watch this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-804/).

Comment: Yep, beyowulf is right, just use point size higher than 20 and that will auto switch to display, anything less is text SF font